# HTML parsing with lxml, python, .tail being broken up by <br> tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I have a website that I am trying to scrape (while not really understanding html) but I have done a ton of reading and made some progress. It's a messy site but the important part looks like this:

```
<h1>
    <b>DESCRIPTOR1: </b> 
       " important content "
    <br>
    <b>DESCRIPTOr2: </b> 
       " important content"
    <hr>
</h1>

<b>Title1</b>
    " A lot of important text"
<br>
<br>
<b>Title2</b>
    "A lot of important text"
<br>
<br>
<b>Title3</b>
<br>
    "1. List of text pertaining to Title3 "
<br>
    "2. List of items for Title 3"
<br> 
    "3. the number of listed items is variable for every page"
<br>
    "4. Sometimes no list at all"
<br>
<br>
<b> Next Title: </b>

....and so on
```

Now I can get pretty close to what I want my final result to be except for when I get to Title 3 and there is a `<br>` before the content that goes with Title 3. This is how I am approaching it:

```
import lxml.html

htmltree = lxml.html.parse('sample.html')

items = htmltree.xpath('//*[@id="sampletext"]/b')

for node in items:

    print (node.text.strip())
    print node.tail
```

Now my 2 problems are (1): I can't strip out whitespaces from the `.tail's` and (2): I get "None" returned for Title3 because there is no `.tail` before the next element which is a `<br>`. Ideally, I would be able to add up any text NOT in between element tags until I get to my next Identifier-Tag which in this case is `<b>`. Hope that makes sense. Any pointers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try using the following XPath expression :**

```
for item in items:
    result = item.xpath('following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()][preceding-sibling::b[1] = $b]', b=item)
    print [r.strip() for r in result]
```

**The output when tested against HTML snippet in question :**

```
['" A lot of important text"']
['"A lot of important text"']
['"1. List of text pertaining to Title3 "', '"2. List of items for Title 3"', '"3. the number of listed items is variable for every page"', '"4. Sometimes no list at all"']
[]
```

**Brief explanation about the XPath :**

- `following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]` : find non-empty, following-sibling text nodes...
- `[preceding-sibling::b[1] = $b]` : ...where the nearest preceding-sibling `b` element equals `$b`. `$b` is an XPath parameter which in the above codes is replaced with current `item`. This is indicated by the 2nd parameter of `xpath()` method (`b=item`)

Comment: Thank you. I don't fully understand it (yet) but trying. The print line is also confusing to me. This works well for the cases where I want everything until the next `b` element even if separated by breaks but there are a couple cases where I just want the immediate stuff after 'b' and not the miscellaneous text. I only want everything until the next 'b' while ignoring 'br' when it is a numbered list. Any easy way to do that?